# JPA-Hibernate OneToOne with lookup table not saving mapped column

Tags: hibernate, jpa, lookup, one-to-one

I am trying to save a parent entity(interest) which uses a lookup table(lookupvalue) using Hibernate. When I persist interest object (`em.persists(interest)`) all the columns are saved except categoryLookupValue.Any clues ?
Here are the details of tables

```
CREATE TABLE interest.interest
(
  id bigint NOT NULL,
  interestname character varying NOT NULL,
  summary character varying NOT NULL,
  legislation character varying,
  description character varying,
  categorylookupvalue integer,<= This column is not saved
  dictionarystartdate date,
  pirstartdate date,
  pirenddate date,
  affectpropertybeforedetail character varying,
  affectpropertyafterdetail character varying,
  CONSTRAINT pk_interest PRIMARY KEY (id),
  CONSTRAINT fk_interest_category FOREIGN KEY (categorylookupvalue)
      REFERENCES reference.lookupvalue (id) MATCH SIMPLE
      ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE NO ACTION
)

CREATE TABLE reference.lookupdomain
(
  id integer NOT NULL,
  name character varying(100) NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT pk_lookupdomain PRIMARY KEY (id)
)

CREATE TABLE reference.lookupvalue
(
  id integer NOT NULL,
  lookupvalue_lookupdomain_id integer NOT NULL,
  domaincode character varying NOT NULL,
  domainvalue character varying NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT pk_lookupvalue PRIMARY KEY (id),
  CONSTRAINT fk_lokupvalue_lookupdomain_id FOREIGN KEY (lookupvalue_lookupdomain_id)
      REFERENCES reference.lookupdomain (id) MATCH SIMPLE
      ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE NO ACTION
)
```

and here are the entities

```
public class Interest implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "id_seq")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "id_seq", sequenceName = "id_seq")
    private Long id;

    @NotNull
    private String interestName;

    @Basic
    private String description;

   // Do not cascade as LookupValue is just for lookup
    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, optional = false)
    // set insertable = false, updatable = false to ensure that JPA doesnt try to update/delete lookup table
    @JoinColumn(name = "categorylookupvalue",referencedColumnName = "id",insertable = false, updatable = false,nullable = false)
    private LookupValue categoryLookupValue;
    ..other fileds
}

public class LookupValue implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "id_seq")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "id_seq", sequenceName = "id_seq")
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "lookupvalue_lookupdomain_id")
    private Long lookupvalue_lookupdomain_id;

    @Column(name = "domaincode")
    private String domainCode;

    @Column(name = "domainvalue")
    private String domainValue;
}

public class LookupDomain implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "id_seq")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "id_seq", sequenceName = "id_seq")
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumns({
            @JoinColumn(name = "lookupvalue_lookupdomain_id", referencedColumnName = "id", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    })
    private List<LookupValue> lookupValue = new ArrayList<>();

}
```

Comment: Well you use `insertable = false`  for `categoryLookupValue` field which would prevent that column being present in any insert statements generated by your persistence provider. This will prevent saving that column to database when using `em.persist` for that entity. To ensure JPA will not update the column once created, just using `updatable = false` is enough

Comment: Thanks @Dark, That fixed the problem.

Comment: insertable = true .. the documentation basicaly says "make that a part of the column list on the insert".  Thanks Ranjeet for the hint, now it "clicks".  Ranjeet, you should add this as the answer so it can property upvoted and marked as "the answer", so this question does not appear unanswered.